# Array of objects return object when condition matched

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array which have value of id, email and password.

```
let array = [
 {id: hyu, email: a@a.com, password: 123},
 {id: rft, email: b@b.com, password: 456},
 {id: ght, email: c@c.com, password: 789},
 {id: kui, email: d@d.com, password: 679}
]
```

Now I would like to return that object when my condition is matched. For that I created a function using javascript `some` function but I want to return the object and we know that `some` function return boolean.

I don't have any idea how to do this.

My code is:

```
const isEmailExists = (email, array) => {
  return array.some(function(el) {
    return el.email === email;
  });
};

if (isEmailExists("c@c.com", array) == true) {
  // I want to work here with returned objects i.e on success case
} else {
  // error case
}
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: You're looking for `.filter()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make use of `.filter()` and check if the filtered array has a length of more than `0`:

```js
let array = [
 {id: 'hyu', email: 'a@a.com', password: 123},
 {id: 'rft', email: 'b@b.com', password: 456},
 {id: 'ght', email: 'c@c.com', password: 789},
 {id: 'kui', email: 'd@d.com', password: 679}
]

let filtered = array.filter(row => row.email === 'a@a.com');

console.log(filtered);

if (filtered.length > 0) { /* mail exists */ }
else { /* mail does not exist */ }
```

Comment: what if we have to make a list of array object and have more conditions? suppose in an array object I need to filter those element whose "name" has "John", "Mark", &  "Kevin" and create another array object of only these 3 people, how to achieve this?

Comment: You can change the callback function in `filter()` to something like this: `array.filter(row => ["John", "Mark", "Kevin"].includes(row.name));`

Answer (score 12):

Assuming the email is unique, you can use `find()`. This will return `null` if not email does not exist.

```js
let array = [{"id":"hyu","email":"a@a.com","password":123},{"id":"rft","email":"b@b.com","password":456},{"id":"ght","email":"c@c.com","password":789},{"id":"kui","email":"d@d.com","password":679}];

const getObject = (email, array) => {
  return array.find(function(el) {
    return el.email === email;
  }) || null;
};

console.log(getObject("c@c.com", array));
```

**Shorter Version:**

```
const getObject = (email, array) => array.find(el => el.email === email ) || null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find()`, not `filter()`, when you expect zero or one match. `find()` will return `undefined` if no match is found and since `undefined` is falsy and any object is truthy, you can use the return value as a condition for an `if` clause directly.

```js
const array = [
 {id: 'hyu', email: 'a@a.com', password: 123},
 {id: 'rft', email: 'b@b.com', password: 456},
 {id: 'ght', email: 'c@c.com', password: 789},
 {id: 'kui', email: 'd@d.com', password: 679}
]

const mail = array.find(row => row.email === 'a@a.com');

if (mail) {
  // Do stuff with mail
  console.log(mail);
} else {
  // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function and hand over the key and the value and filter the array.

```js
function getObjects(array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(object => object[key] === value);
}

let array = [{ id: 'hyu', email: 'a@a.com', password: 123 }, { id: 'rft', email: 'b@b.com', password: 456 }, { id: 'ght', email: 'c@c.com', password: 789 }, { id: 'kui', email: 'd@d.com', password: 679 }];

console.log(getObjects(array, 'email', 'c@c.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const found = array.find(item => (item.email === 'a@a.com')) || null;
console.log(found);
```