# Javascript: How to iterate through an array looking for an object value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have a js file that is just a an array with the name and type of person. I am trying to write a function in my other file to iterate through that array of objects and return just the object that matches a certain criteria. Here is my code.

person.js

```
export const persons_options = [
  { 
     name: 'Andrew',
     type: 'Athlete',
  },
  { 
     name: 'Paul',
     type: 'Worker',
  },
  { 
     name: 'Phil',
     type: 'Developer',
  },
 
]
```

utils.js

```
// params initialized already
person_type = params.subType
const name = persons_options.map((option) => {
    if(person_type === option.type){
        return option.name
    }
})

const person = name
```

The issue is I know map creates a new array so the output is `,,Phil`. How would I just return one of the object names instead of all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array of objects return object when condition matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491211/array-of-objects-return-object-when-condition-matched)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find() will do the work

```js
let persons_options = [
  { 
     name: 'Andrew',
     type: 'Athlete',
  },
  { 
     name: 'Paul',
     type: 'Worker',
  },
  { 
     name: 'Phil',
     type: 'Developer',
  },
 
]

let obj = persons_options.find(o => o.type === 'Developer');
//to return name
console.log("name",obj.name);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `find` function.

See here the list of functions that you can call on an array:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods

`filter` might best suit your case if multiple results may be returned.